# How to Center an element and have a own line

Tags: html, css, frontend

I want the style of this page of mine to be justified in the center but it doesn't work.

Especially for the converter tab I want each element to have its own line and must be centered inside the `div` container.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.converter-tab {
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  background: #6943ff;
  width: 550px;
  height: 285px;
}

.converter-input {
  width: 117px;
  height: 83px;
  background: none;
  border: solid 1px white;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.converter-btn {
  width: 117px;
  height: 42px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
}

.output {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  color: #5a537b;
  width: 550px;
  height: 400px;
}

.length,
.volume,
.mass {
  width: 500px;
  height: 108px;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Unit Conversion</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="converter-tab">
      <h2>Metric/Imperial Unit Conversion</h2>
      <input type="text" id="input-el" class="converter-input" />
      <button class="converter-btn" id="convert-btn">Convert</button>
    </div>

    <div class="output">
      <div class="length" id="length-el">
        <h2>Length (Meter/Feeet)</h2>
        <p class="" id="output-el"></p>
      </div>

      <div class="volume" id="volume-el">
        <h2>Volume (Liters/Gallons)</h2>
        <p class="" id="output-el2"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="mass" id="mass-el">
        <h2>Mass (Kilograms/Pounds)</h2>
        <p class="" id="output-el3"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried the display block and in-line block but the element inside the container is not moving.

Answer (score 0):

i think the container class is the implemented one because he is the in the general div that contain the "converter-tab" div , and the reason of not-centered elements is  the padding and margin css classes.
try to remove it or replace it by this one :

```
.container {
  margin:  auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you really have to do in this case is to assign a property `text-align: center`
to your `.converter-tab` class and moreover you have to wrap your `h2`, `input` and `button` individually inside a separate div for each one.

You can check my working snippet below:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.converter-tab {
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  background: #6943ff;
  width: 550px;
  height: 285px;
  text-align: center;
}

.converter-input {
  width: 117px;
  height: 83px;
  background: none;
  border: solid 1px white;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.converter-btn {
  width: 117px;
  height: 42px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
}

.output {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  color: #5a537b;
  width: 550px;
  height: 400px;
}

.length,
.volume,
.mass {
  width: 500px;
  height: 108px;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Unit Conversion</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="converter-tab">
       <div><h2>Metric/Imperial Unit Conversion</h2></div>
       <div><input type="text" id="input-el" class="converter-input" /></div>
       <div><button class="converter-btn" id="convert-btn">Convert</button></div>
    </div>

    <div class="output">
      <div class="length" id="length-el">
        <h2>Length (Meter/Feeet)</h2>
        <p class="" id="output-el"></p>
      </div>

      <div class="volume" id="volume-el">
        <h2>Volume (Liters/Gallons)</h2>
        <p class="" id="output-el2"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="mass" id="mass-el">
        <h2>Mass (Kilograms/Pounds)</h2>
        <p class="" id="output-el3"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've annotated your css below. I've made your input div children [block level elements](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp) so they appear on their own line. I've then added [margin: auto](https://youtu.be/Azfj1efPAH0) to them to make them centered. I've aligned text to the center using [text-align: center](https://blog.hubspot.com/website/center-div-css);

Alignment is always a PITA (much less so these days) but there's a handy tool to use to help you: [howtocenterincss.com](http://howtocenterincss.com/)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.converter-tab {
  color: white;
  background: #6943ff;
  width: 550px;
  height: 285px;
}

.converter-tab > * {
  display: block; /* make each item a block element so it appears on its own line */
  text-align: center; /* make text (e.g. inside <p> tags) centered */
  margin-inline: auto; /* make block level elements centered */
}

.converter-input {
  width: 117px;
  height: 83px;
  background: none;
  border: solid 1px white;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem; /*just added this to neaten it up a smidge */
}

.converter-btn {
  width: 117px;
  height: 42px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
}

.output {
  text-align: center; /* center the text in your output div */
  background: #f4f4f4;
  color: #5a537b;
  width: 550px;
  height: 400px;
}

.length,
.volume,
.mass {
  width: 500px;
  height: 108px;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="converter-tab">
    <h2>Metric/Imperial Unit Conversion</h2>
    <input type="text" id="input-el" class="converter-input" />
    <button class="converter-btn" id="convert-btn">Convert</button>
  </div>

  <div class="output">
    <div class="length" id="length-el">
      <h2>Length (Meter/Feet)</h2>
      <p class="" id="output-el"></p>
    </div>

    <div class="volume" id="volume-el">
      <h2>Volume (Liters/Gallons)</h2>
      <p class="" id="output-el2"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="mass" id="mass-el">
      <h2>Mass (Kilograms/Pounds)</h2>
      <p class="" id="output-el3"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As it's acceptably supported all over major browsers I'd use flex: just change the display mode of your container div to `flex`, set `flex-direction: column;` and `justify-content: center;`. After this adjust top and bottom padding as you prefer.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.converter-tab {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  background: #6943ff;
  width: 550px;
  height: 285px;
}

.converter-input {
  width: 117px;
  height: 83px;
  background: none;
  border: solid 1px white;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.converter-btn {
  width: 117px;
  height: 42px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
}

.output {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  color: #5a537b;
  width: 550px;
  height: 400px;
}

.length,
.volume,
.mass {
  width: 500px;
  height: 108px;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Unit Conversion</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="converter-tab">
      <h2>Metric/Imperial Unit Conversion</h2>
      <input type="text" id="input-el" class="converter-input" />
      <button class="converter-btn" id="convert-btn">Convert</button>
    </div>

    <div class="output">
      <div class="length" id="length-el">
        <h2>Length (Meter/Feeet)</h2>
        <p class="" id="output-el"></p>
      </div>

      <div class="volume" id="volume-el">
        <h2>Volume (Liters/Gallons)</h2>
        <p class="" id="output-el2"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="mass" id="mass-el">
        <h2>Mass (Kilograms/Pounds)</h2>
        <p class="" id="output-el3"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```